# GroceryCRUD error

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

Fala galera estou tentando utilizar o [GroceryCRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/) junto com o Framework [Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/)  estou fazendo a instalação exatamente como indicado no vídeo tutorial do grocery mas mesmo sem alterar nada esta me retornando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como sou iniciante pesquise, mudei as versões dos frameworks mas nada de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando mais um pouco acabei descobrindo que se tratava de um bug do proprio codeigniter 3.1.3 onde apenas mudando a linha

```
get_object_vars($object)
```

para

```
get_object_vars($vars)
```

no seguinte arquivo e linha system\core\Loader.php linha 1381.

Comment: Não é muito saudável modificar a o *framework* pra resolver um problema de outra biblioteca. Mais sensato é [estender](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#creating-core-system-classes) a classe, assim, quando você atualizar o `CodeIgniter`, não vai ter problema com a classe alterada.